# Weather data google-maps-api v3

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, weather-api, google-weather-api

I have a google maps api where after displaying the map I am going to insert a few markers.
On click of these markers, I am bringing data regarding that marker.

Now the problem is I want the wind speed also for that marker .I got response from one of the architects in stackoverflow that google weather api is no
longer maintained by google and deprecated.

Is there any to achieve this without using any paid external plugins?

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at the API from: http://openweathermap.org/ that should help you out.